# React Native Maps - takeSnapshot not capturing markers

Tags: react-native, maps, react-native-maps

react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz
react: 16.13.1
react-native-maps: 0.28.0

I want to get markers as a part of the snapshot. When we use `takeSnapshot` method all markers are ignored.

```js
const snapshot = this.viewRefTest.takeSnapshot({
  format: 'png', // image formats: 'png', 'jpg' (default: 'png')
  quality: 0.5, // image quality: 0..1 (only relevant for jpg, default: 1)
  result: 'file', // result types: 'file', 'base64' (default: 'file')
});

<MapView
  ref={(viewRefTest) => {
    this.viewRefTest = viewRefTest;
  }}
  showsUserLocation={true}
  followUserLocation={true}>
  <MapView.Marker coordinate={item.location}>
    <Image
      style={{ width: 30, height: 30 }}
      source={require('../../assets/images/trophy.png')}
    />
    <Callout style={{ width: 250, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>$23</Text>
      <View>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 12 }}>Custom Text!</Text>
      </View>
    </Callout>
  </MapView.Marker>
</MapView>;
```

Please let me know the possibility of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After too many tries & combinations of adding delays, height/width, I was not able to capture custom markers using `takeSnapshot` method.

As a workaround, I have used `captureRef` method of `react-native-view-shot`

https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot

```
const uri = await captureRef(this.viewRefTest, {
            format: "png",
            quality: 1
        })

<MapView
  ref={(viewRefTest) => {
    this.viewRefTest = viewRefTest;
  }}
  showsUserLocation={true}
  followUserLocation={true}>
  <MapView.Marker coordinate={item.location}>
    <Image
      style={{ width: 30, height: 30 }}
      source={require('../../assets/images/trophy.png')}
    />
    <Callout style={{ width: 250, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>$23</Text>
      <View>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 12 }}>Custom Text!</Text>
      </View>
    </Callout>
  </MapView.Marker>
</MapView>
```

`CaptureRef` Returns a Promise of the image URI. It helps capture a React Native view to an image. We can mention height, width, quality & format for the captured image.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try use width and height?

```js
const snapshot = this.viewRefTest.takeSnapshot({
  width: 500,
  height: 500,
  format: 'png',
  quality: 0.5,
  result: 'file',
});

snapshot.then((uri) => {
  console.log(uri);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that by creating a Snapshot with ["react-native-view-shot"](https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I think this bug depends on when you call `this.viewRefTest.takeSnapshot()`

You can check in my https://expo.dev/@duongtungls/expo-map-view-example

I think call `takeSnapshot` just after map mounted won't get marker or map.
If call after callback `onMapReady` still need wait some hundreds of milisecond to take fully snapshot for both map and marker.

I hope this example code can help you solve problem.

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import MapView, { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export default function App() {
  const mapRef = useRef(null);
  const [uri, setUri] = useState(null);

  const takeSnapshot = useCallback(() => {
    if (!mapRef || !mapRef.current) {
      return;
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      const snapshot = mapRef.current.takeSnapshot({
        format: 'png', // image formats: 'png', 'jpg' (default: 'png')
        quality: 0.5, // image quality: 0..1 (only relevant for jpg, default: 1)
        result: 'file', // result types: 'file', 'base64' (default: 'file')
      });
      snapshot.then((uri) => {
        setUri(uri);
      });
    }, 800); // I add some timeout delay because without delay snapnot won't have map or marker.
  }, [mapRef]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {!uri && (
        <MapView
          ref={mapRef}
          style={{
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
          }}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}
          onMapReady={takeSnapshot} // I think need wait for map ready to take snapshot but seem still need wait by setTimeout to get fully snapshot
        >
          <Marker
            coordinate={{
              latitude: 37.78825,
              longitude: -122.4324,
            }}
            title={'Test'}
          >
            <Ionicons name="trophy" size={32} color="red" />
            <Text>This is a marker</Text>
          </Marker>
        </MapView>
      )}
      {uri && (
        <Image
          style={{
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            resizeMode: 'contain',
            borderColor: 'red',
            borderWidth: 10,
          }}
          source={{
            uri,
          }}
        />
      )}
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Snapshot take after map mounted

[image]

Snapshot take after onMapReady and 800ms delay

[image]

Best regards,